# Do static classes used in different jars in the same program access the same data?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Well, the title says most of it. I searched and most people don't really answer what I'm trying to get at. In Minecraft plugins, you make jars of code that get run by Bukkit/Spiggot. If I create a static class that is used in multiple jars, but inside the same program(Bukkit), so they act statically and share data?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is *no*. Your program is the *.jar*. They are all different programs.

Comment: It depends on the application framework and if it uses a scoped ClassLoader.  Some examples of frameworks that use scoped ClassLoaders: JBoss AS, WebSphere.  Some frameworks that don't: Raw JVM, Struts.

Comment: @Gendarme: "program" != "jar".  A program uses jars, and sometimes is collected into a jar, but to say that a program is a jar is a horrible misunderstanding.

Comment: What do you mean by "static class"? What do you mean by "data"? Public classes contained in different .jars  that are loaded by the same classloader can access each other.

Comment: They should; what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Samuel Thanks, that's pretty much what I was wondering about. I have something in mind that might use this, but it is a _ton_ of code, and I didn't want to be 4 hours in to find out it didn't. xD If you want to put this as an answer, I'll select it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public classes loaded by the same classloader, regardless of where they are defined (same or different .jar, .class, etc), are in the same scope which  means they can access each other.

Comment: This is great for overriding mostly anything that can be overriden. :D That made no sense I know just think about it.

Answer (score 3):

Jar files are not a unit of scoping or encapsulation in Java.  They are simply sources from which a `ClassLoader` can load classes and resources, and that can carry additional metadata.  Java code has no (direct) sense of the Jar, if any, from which a given class was loaded, and once loaded, classes are global to the VM<sup>*</sup>.

Supposing that all the classes in question are loaded by the same or suitably-related `ClassLoader`s, there will be at most one in the VM for each distinct, fully-qualifed class name, and all references to each class name will refer to the same class.  If that class has static variables, then they will be shared among all objects that access the class.

<sup>*</sup>Classes are, however, scoped by the `ClassLoader` that loaded them, so it is possible to have distinct classes with the same name in one VM.  Although I do not know Minecraft implementation details, it seems unlikely that it would be leveraging that capability.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "maybe".

In a raw JVM, the <s>static</s> class is loaded by a universal ClassLoader, so all references to that static class will refer to the same data stored in the static members of that class.

In more complicated frameworks, scoped ClassLoaders segregate accessibility of data between application components.  In this case, two separate components might have different references to the "same" class.  The rules here get tricky .. because it's hard to understand, and because sometimes there are bugs visibility between the component scopes may or may not "leak" or there might be a scoping boundary that you're not expecting.

Comment: So, in the use of Bukkit, where you compile your plugins, then Bukkit loads the jars, would it work?

Comment: I'm not sure what bukkit does in this regard.

Comment: What do you mean "static" class? `Static` is only an acceptable keyword for class when regarding inner classes that don't have access to their containing instance. Your first statement is false. There is no such thing as a "universal classloader" either.

Comment: Abstract class with static members?  Interfaces with public-static-final declarations?  There are lots of ways to emulate static class data in Java.  Not that there is "A universal classloader" just that in the case of a basic JVM run the application really only uses one (yes, a simplification -- you can go find details about the hierarchy of various classloaders if you care that much).

Comment: @CodyRichardson Yes bukkit loads your plugin. You can override things that bukkit uses. Ex: I overrided how permission were handled in bukkit with my plugin and now every plugin follows my rules/override system.